# Find total number of (i,j) pairs in an array such that i<j and a[i]+a[j]=i+j.

Tags: c++, logic

I have a naive solution which uses two loops, but I want to improve the time complexity as O(nlogn). Any better approach available?

The array is unsorted and can have negative values too.

Sample Test Case:
Array: 1 0 3 2

Output:
4

Explanation:
Indices - (0,1), (0,3), (1,2), (2,3) are the pairs which satisfy the given constraints.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please read this [open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems).

Comment: Are you allowed to sort the array?

Comment: What am I to do after I found the pairs?

Comment: You can sort the array. But you won't be able to satisfy the condition i<j

Comment: I have a O(n^2) naive approach. Could it be optimized for n = 10^6 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem:  `find (i,j), i<j, s.t. a[i] + a[j] = i + j`

I propose the following approach:

1. Set `b[i] = a[i] - i`
   The problem becomes: `find (i,j), i<j, s.t. b[i] + b[j] = 0`
   Complexity: O(n)
2. Create objects `c[i] = (b[i],i)`, a struct for example, in a std::vector (or std::array)
   Complexity: O(n)
3. Sort the `c[i]` pairs according to `b` values -> get `d[j] = (v[j], i[j])` , sorted array
   Complexity: O(nlogn)
4. Find all pairs `j,k` such that `v[j] = -v[k]`
   Complexity: the array being sorted, should be O(n)
5. keep the cases `i[j] < i[k]`
   Complexity: O(n)

Comment: I think you can get rid of extra pair and only keep step 1, 3 and 4, `i < j` restriction is to count pair only once [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/719116e7ab25ae85).

Comment: (corrected) @Jarod42 You are perfectly right if we want to count  the number of pairs only. In the exemple provided by the OP, he also gave pairs of indices as results. So I proposed this extra pair in step 2 to be exhaustive. Having 5 steps looks more serious than having 3 steps only :)

Comment: @Jarod42 I just noticed your code (Demo). I am impressed by your rapidity.