# Find indices i<j in an array of size n so that the sum of values at those indices is equal to i + j

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting

My solution :

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

int main() {
    int n;//Size of array
    std::cin>>n;
    std::vector<long long>vec_int;
    int temp = n;
    while(n--){
        long long k ;
        std::cin>>k;
        vec_int.push_back(k);
    }
    n = temp;
    int num = 0;
    for(int  i = 0 ; i < n-1 ; i++){
        for(int j = i+1; j<n; j++){
            if(i<j && i+j == vec_int[i]+vec_int[j])
                num++;
        }
    }

    std::cout<<num;

    return 0;
}
```

I am scanning the array which takes about `O(n^2)` time. On very large arrays the time limit for the question exceeds the 2s duration. I tried sorting the array but didn't get too far. How can I speed this up? Is it possible to do this in `O(n)` time complexity.

Comment: So, for array `[2,1,3,8,6,5] `, `i` and `j` are `1` and `5`. Is that correct?

Comment: Also, in your code `i<j` is a redundant check.

Comment: Yes. `i` goes upto the second last element. `j` goes to the last element. I will removed the redundancy but it still didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Now, why was this downvoted? Any explanation? What did I do wrong?

Comment: I didn't down vote and yes I am seeing if there is a better solution.

Comment: The question was already asked recently at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53343473/find-total-number-of-i-j-pairs-in-an-array-such-that-ij-and-aiaj-ij?s=5|0.0000 but with a slightly different answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider redefinition of your problem. The expression:

```
i+j == vec_int[i]+vec_int[j]
```

is algebraically equivalent to:

```
vec_int[i] - i == -(vec_int[j] - j)
```

So define:

```
a[i] = vec_int[i] - i
```

And now the question is to count how many times `a[i] == -a[j]`.

This can be tested in `O(n)`. Use `unordered_map m` to count how many times each negative value is present in `a`. Then for each positive value `a[i]` will be paired with `m[-a[i]]` negative values. Also count number of zeroes in `a` and compute number of pairs between those.

Comment: Nice observation!

Comment: Note a similar but different answer for the same question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53343473/find-total-number-of-i-j-pairs-in-an-array-such-that-ij-and-aiaj-ij?s=5|0.0000

Comment: It seems to me that using an unordered_map will be O(nlogn)

Comment: @Damien, `unordered_map` has average constant time access.

Comment: I was thinking on the construction, not the access, but I was wrong effectively. Your method should be faster than mine for very large n, not sure for intermediate values on n.

Comment: `Then for each positive value a[i] will be paired with m[-a[i]] negative values.` Can you explain a little bit what is going on here? Also wouldn't counting paired 0s make the algorithm `O(n^2)`?

Comment: @AbhishekJha, if you have 5 values of `-7` then every value of `7` will be paired with 5 values of `-7`. You can count zeroes in linear time. Having `n` zeroes results in `n(n-1)/2` pairs of distinct zeroes.